# Why a pointer is unmutated even after passed to a function as reference?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, traversal

The function "hasPath" is given a pointer to a root of a binary tree and two integers. It returns if there's a path between integer a to integer b. I thought I can use a helper function "find" to find integer "a" in the tree and change the pointer as reference, then from the tree node of "a" to find integer b. However, the find function didn't change the pointer that was passed by reference.

//helper function to find an integer in a tree whose root node is passed in as reference

```
bool find(BinaryTreeNode*&node, int a){
    if (node==nullptr){
        return false;
    } else if (node->data==a){
        return true;

    }else {
        return find(node->left, a) or find(node->right, a);

    }
}


//a function returns if there is a path between integer a and b in the 
//binary tree passed in as root node

bool hasPath(BinaryTreeNode* node, int a, int b){
    if (node==nullptr) return false;
    BinaryTreeNode*temp = node;

    return find(temp,a) //the pointer temp should be changed, but didn't
            and 
            find(temp, b);

}
```

Comment: Which line in `find` is supposed to change `node`?

Comment: You never assign to the `node` variable, even if you did the recursion would then mess up your tree

Comment: @melpomene: the & in the "find" should change the tree node "temp"

Comment: @ChenYao Why would it do that? Consider `int x = 42; int &r = x;`. Why would the `&` in `&r` change `x`?

Comment: passing by reference allow to change parameter, but you don't have instruction to change it inside the function.

Comment: @AlanBirties  Could you please elaborate a little more? How could I "assign to the node variable", please? I 'cout' the 'temp->data' after calling the 'find(temp, a)', but the 'temp' still points to the root of the tree. Would the 'find' function change the 'temp' node to where 'a' locate? Thank you!

Comment: To assign to a variable, you use the `=` operator.

Comment: @ChenYao - the `&` means the pointer is passed by reference, and (since it is not `const`) the function CAN change the value of the pointer, not that it will.   The only circumstances in which the value of the pointer will change is if the function assigns a value to the pointer, or passes the reference to another called function that assigns to it.    Your code does not assign to the pointer, nor does it pass the reference to another function that assigns to it.   Hence the pointer remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in your `find` function assigns to the `node` reference, so the `temp` variable in `hasPath` is unchanged.

To make this work you should change `hasPath` so that it **returns** the node you are interested in. There's no need to use a reference. For some reason newbies often overlook the fact that functions can return values.

Change `find` to this

```
BinaryTreeNode* find(BinaryTreeNode* node, int a)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr; // return nullptr for not found
    }
    else if (node->data == a)
    {
        return node; // found the node
    }
    else
    {
        // recurse left or right
        BinaryTreeNode* temp = find(node->left, a);
        return temp ? temp : find(node->right, a);
    }
}
```

Then change `hasPath` to use the returned node

```
bool hasPath(BinaryTreeNode* node, int a, int b)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
        return false;
    node = find(node, a);
    if (node == nullptr)
        return false;
    node = find(node, b);
    if (node == nullptr)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

BTW I'm not making any comment on the validity of your algorithm, but I believe the code above is what you were trying to implement.